# I'm having an extremely difficult time deploying my Meteor app to DigitalOcean

Tags: meteor, deployment

I've read so many tutorials, issue reports online and still can't seem to connect and deploy correctly to my DO droplet. I'm attempting to deploy my Meteor app with MUP.

This is the current error I have:

[image]

In most cases, this has something to do with an older version of Node. I changed the Node version on the mup.setting file to 0.10.40 and still have errors. If I completely remove NodeJS from my target machine, delete all files and remnants of Node and NPM and then try `mup` again, I get the following error:

[image]

I have literally tried everything to get my Meteor app to deploy, but nothing works. I've been at this for what is now the 2nd day and no luck.

This is what I have done so far:

- Tried using regular mup (used it with init in a new folder inside my
  meteor app, mup setup then mup deploy). Get numerous errors using mup
  in general.
- Tried using mupx to deploy my app, get the same errors.
- Completely wiped NodeJS, npm from target server repeatedly and tried deploying with no luck.
- Deleted entire DO droplet and tried mup again. Deleted and created another new DO droplet to try mupx again. No luck either time.
- Changed the `deployCheckWaitTime` to 120, 200, 300, etc, etc with no success.
- Tried to manually deploy my meteor up via Upstart, but my myapp.tar.gz file is never created and I can't progress further than that.
- Increased size of my DO droplet

I really have no idea what to do at this point. I feel like I tried everything and it's driving me insane.

Edit:

After fixing the MongoDB issue, this is the new error...I guess there are folders not present that are supposed to be present?

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1069
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1070
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1071
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1072
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1073
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1074
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1075
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1076
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1077
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1078
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1079
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1080
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1081
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1082
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1083
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1084
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1085
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1086
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1087
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1088
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1089
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1090
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1091
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1092
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1093
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1094
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Script restart attempt #1095
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1096
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Script restart attempt #1097
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1098
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Script restart attempt #1099
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1100
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Script restart attempt #1101
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1102
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1103
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1104
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1105
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1106
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1107
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1108
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Script restart attempt #1109
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1110
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1111
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1112
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1113
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1114
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1115
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1116
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1117
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1118
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1119
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1120
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1121
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1122
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Script restart attempt #1123
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1124
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1125
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1126
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1127
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1128
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1129
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1130
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1131
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1132
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1133
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1134
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1135
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1136
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1137
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1138
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1139
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1140
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1141
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1142
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1143
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1144
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1145
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1146
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1147
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1148
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1149
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1150
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1151
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1152
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1153
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1154
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1155
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1156
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1157
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1158
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1159
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1160
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1161
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 127
error: Script restart attempt #1162

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 15: /proc/self/fd/9: forever: not found
```

Comment: Can you try setting up mup *outside* your Meteor project directory and see how it goes from there? Make sure your mup directory settings file points to your Meteor project directory; that mup is installed globally via npm or else locally in your mup directory; and that the node.js version is '0.10.40' in your settings file. then run `mup setup` and finally `mup deploy` from the mup directory. if there's an error, run `mup logs -n 300` and reprint it in your question.

Comment: @JeremyS. Sure. I'll try that right now.

Comment: @JeremyS. Posted the error in the OP.

Comment: I want to add that I'm not installing MongoDB. I'm using MongoDB via Compose and therefore, I set the Mongo installation to false and have an extra `MONGO_URL` key in "env."

Comment: What does it say when you run `mup logs -n 300` from the mup directory? The same as the stderr you reprinted above, or something different?

Comment: @JeremyS. I apologize for posting the wrong info. I have updated the post with the logs -n 300 error.

Comment: It is complaining about a Mongo connection. Can you confirm (1) that your app is running correctly in dev when listening on the local db, and (2) that you can log into your Compose shell using the credentials in your mup MONGO_URL setting? e.g., `mongo capital.2.mongolayer.com:<portNumber>/<dbName> -u '<username>' -p <password>`

Comment: @JeremyS. Alright. Looks like I fixed the MongoDB problem. I didn't realize that Compose has a special Mongo node for Meteor/Node apps. Now that the Mongo problem seems fixed, I have a new error, which I will add in my OP.

Comment: This may be caused by you wiping node and npm from your droplet as you described. Also, "setupNode" should be true in your settings file. Either mup will need to install node or you will need to do so yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did and it keeps throwing that same error. I'm gonna look into this and see if I can fix it.

Comment: @JeremyS. Hey, I deployed my app without Compose's MongoDB and everything went smooth. If you want, you can respond to my question with the MongoDB suggestion so I can upvote you. Your suggestion made it possible for me to complete my deployment and helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion we had in the comments, which led to a partial solution:

- Most importantly, `mup` should be initialized and setup in a directory *outside* of your Meteor project directory.
- Run `mup logs -n 300` or a similar mup logging command to get more information any time there is a failed deploy. This is in the SOP identified in the mup repo and leads to most of the fixed tickets.
- Run `mup setup` after updating the node version in your mup settings file.
- Node/npm do not need to be manually setup on, or wiped from, a new DO droplet, and may cause problems if you try (not sure). Mup does this for you.
- Check to ensure you can remote into a hosted db connection using the credentials supplied in your settings `MONGO_URL`. If you can't access it from the terminal using the supplied combination of db, port, username and password, `mup` won't be able to set it up either.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your (edited) nip.json file and tell us what OS you have installed on DigitalOcean. I had no problems with Ubuntu, the stated Node and remote Mongolabs. But remember to run mup setup after changing things like do/don't install node/mongo